# Apply position: fixed to a div while maintaining auto-width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an open dialog window which has a resizable width and a max-height which induces scrolling. I would like to position a div (or multiple elements, if necessary) at the top of this dialog such that, when I scroll, the div remains visible. I would also like the div's width to fill that of the dialog.

So, I start with some basic HTML mark-up:

```
<div id="dialog">
    <div id="dialogHeader"><div>
    <div id="dialogContents"></div>
</div>
```

At this point, dialogHeader's width automatically scales to fit dialog's width. However, if I scroll down through dialogContents, dialogHeader scrolls out of the viewport.

I experience the opposite issue when marking dialogHeader with "position: fixed;" Now, it stays in the viewport, but its width shrinks to that of its contents.

If I set dialogHeader's width to 100% then it expands far outside of the dialog.

Is there any trick to achieving both of these effects? Or do I need to monitor the dialog's width using jQuery and automatically adjust dialogHeader's width?

Here's a screenshot showing my element at the top of the dialog with its position set to fixed. Note that you can see the green background not covering the entirety of the top. [image]

Comment: Yep. The dialog has a scrollbar. I've edited in a screenshot of the scenario.

Comment: Can you just put the scrollbar on the content div instead of the outer div?

Comment: Potentially. I just thought this would be the path of least resistance because max height is set at the dialog level for all dialogs in this application. Restricting content height in a subset of dialogs could lead to potential doubly-nested scrollbars / other irregularities... Just curious if it is possible this way first. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position the window contents separately and absolutely within the window container, and use `overflow:auto` to force the contents to scroll instead of overflowing/growing their parent.

You can just put any top-floater elements in the parent context.

<kbd>[**Sample implementation on JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/DGuEB/2/)</kbd>

Note that you can resize the output window at will to test how it resizes.

Comment: See the comments.  He does not want to move the scrollbar to the contents, he would like to keep it on the overall dialog.

Comment: I changed the fiddle to add the floating search box, but if this isn't what he's looking for I completely misunderstand the question hehe.